# Invalid Operation Error when rvmsudo apt-get on ubuntu 12.04.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, nginx, rvm, passenger

We are using rvm 1.19.0 to install libcurl4-openssl-dev （for passenger and nginx for rails). However there was an error. Then we run the following as suggested:

```
$export rvmsudo_secure_path=1
```

Now there is another error of invalid operation as below:

```
ubuntu@$ rvmsudo apt-get libcurl4-openssl-dev
E: Invalid operation libcurl4-openssl-dev
```

What's wrong with the rvm? Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rvmsudo apt-get install libcurl4-openssl-dev`